# How to use the element I check with .has() using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how I could use the element that I check with .has() using jQuery.
This is what I have so far

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <!--Only this paragraph should have a red background -->
    <p>This is a paragraph</p> 
    <h1>This is not a paragraph</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>This is not a paragraph</h1>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div").has("p").addClass("para");
```

As you can see, I ask if my div has a `<p>` and if so to add a class. My intention was to add the class to the paragraph but it seem to be that the class is added to my division. How can I add the class to my `<p>` after using `$("div").has("p")`?

I should put it in an `if` statement like this

```
if($("div").has("p")){
    {...}.addClass("para");
}
```

but how can I add the class to my `<p>`?

I have a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/JaNzv/2/)** to make it clear

(I know I could use .each() for this problem but I want to know if it's possible with .has() too?)

Comment: Don't overcomplicate, you don't need to use `has()`, just use an appropriate selector (which will only select the relevant elements).

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah I know, but I was just wondering if it's possible with .has() too?

Comment: No, it is not posible with `.has()`

Answer (score 3):

simply you can use

```
$("div p").addClass("para");
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien `My intention was to add the class to the paragraph`

Answer (score 1):

While I recommend that you follow Mr. Aliens suggestion, if you absolutely must use .has() you have to first select the paragraph. When you write it like this:

```
$("div").has("p").addClass("para");
```

Your selected element is still the div(s).
If you want to avoid writing an If-statement, write the check this way:

```
$("div").has("p").find("p").addClass("para");
```

EDIT: This doesn't really check IF the div contains a paragraph, but rather selects the ones that have. The result is basically the same.

Comment: I'm adding this comment here since I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer I wanted to comment on. If you actually want to return a bool, you have to write $("div").has("p").length ? true : false.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").has("p").find('p').addClass('class_name'); 
// It will add class on p if div has p element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("div").find("p").length != 0) {
  // another way to check if there is a p element inside of a div
  $("div").find("p").addClass("para");
}
```

OR if you are not **happy** with this you can change jQuery's has function to this

```
has: function( target ) {
    var i,
        targets = jQuery( target, this ),
        len = targets.length,
        has = false;

    this.filter(function() {
        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            if ( jQuery.contains( this, targets[i] ) ) {
                has = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return has;
},
```

Comment: Look at the fiddle it works, find out that you are right before voting down, man.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy so why then the next div does not have class para? How did you earn such a big reputation?????

Comment: @user3796431: i think you haven't reat the question yet. he want to do it using has

Comment: @AmitKumar Doing that with `.has()` is a way of crack-potter.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: i agree with you. but it doesn't allow any one to give answer in another way. we can suggest him , by this method you can not do this .

Comment: @user3796431: why you are doing so many line of code, if it can be done in single line
`$("div > p").addClass( "para" );`

Comment: @AmitKumar Just leave this. :D and we shall mind our business. :)